Connecting multiple Li-Pos, each with a separate BMS
I have some 3.7v Li-Po batteries, each has a welded BMS, and they're all the same capacity.
I need to connect them to get 11.1V and also be able to charge it.
Would that be possible, or the BMS will give me trouble?

each has a welded BMS are you sure they are BMS? They could be DW-01 overcharge/overdischarge protection boards. Could you please show a photo or put a link to datasheet or at least part number?

@RohatKılıç Hmm.. I'm not pretty sure. Here's a pic:  https://makerselectronics.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/3.7V-350mAH-KP-401235-lipo-Battery-3-1-1000x1000.jpg

I am 90+% sure it's a protection circuit, not a BMS. I see two SOT-23-5 (or -6) chips: One DW-01 or a similar sh*te with a different colour, the other the MOSFET to cut charging/discharging in case of an abnormal issue.
